# Hi friends i just now installed opencv and checking the basic code but it results in error. The code is :

Tags: python-3.x

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(True):
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    # Our operations on the frame come here
    gray = cv2.cvtColor('frame', cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
    cv2.imshow('gray',gray)
    if cv2.waitKey(20) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()`

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Kouissi\Desktop\camera-test\camera_test.py", line 11, in <module>
    gray = cv2.cvtColor('frame', cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
TypeError: Expected cv::UMat for argument 'src'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change:

```
gray = cv2.cvtColor('frame', cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

to:

```
gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

In this case the frame variable is a numpy array.

Comment: Another error:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Kouissi\Desktop\camera-test\camera_test.py", line 14, in <module>
    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.0.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:625: error: (-2:Unspecified error) The function is not implemented. Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Cocoa support. If you are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then re-run cmake or configure script in function 'cvShowImage'

Comment: @MOHAMEDKOUISSI I have not seen that error before, but it looks like you need to install an additional software library called libgtk2.0-dev. What operating system do you use...like, iOS, Windows, Ubuntu, etc...?

Comment: Windows is the operating system